# Parametrization of the intersection of two linear surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

I need to find the parametrization of the intersection for the two surfaces defined by these equations: $3x-4y+5z=3$ and $-x+2y-4z=10$
I'm not really sure how to do it. What is the best way?

Comment: There’s no such thing as *the* parameterization. There are many. Is there some particular form that you’re supposed to end up with? The most straightforward way is to simply solve the system of equations. It doesn’t have a unique solution, so a formula for the solution set will be a parameterization.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Set $z = 0$ (or any constant you like), then solve the remaining system of two variables.

$\textbf{Comment}$: Honestly, you have a choice in which variable you want to eliminate in the initial step, I usually just go for $z$. In either case you will left to solve a system of 2 linear equations with 2 unknowns.

The above will give you a point $p$ in the intersection of the two planes. The parametrization of the line of intersection is $p+ t(\vec{n_1} \times \vec{n}_2)$ where $\vec{n}_i$ is the normal for plane $P_i$.

Comment: I don't get the point of making one variable to zero. Wouldn't you mean set $z=\lambda$ and solve for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It could be the case that you get an inconsistent system when you set $z = 0$ (no solutions). In most cases these calc III questions can be solved by eliminating a variable in which you can set it to any constant you like. So yes, if you want to be safe, let $\lambda$ be any non-zero real number. Check my edit above.

Comment: I see now the method. I like the cross product thing. I was thinking of getting directly the parametrization with $\lambda$ as parameter.

Comment: @RafaBudría: if you are satisfied, please accept, to close question.

Comment: :) It's not mine.

Comment: My mistake. That is meant for the OP.